# Save and Restore tensor flow tf.contrib model

Tags: python, tensorflow

There are plenty of examples for how to save a tensorflow model using a `tf.train.Saver` object, but I was wondering how to save a model that comes from `tf.contrib`. For example using the code from the quickstart demo at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/tflearn/index.html:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Data sets
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TEST,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)

# Specify that all features have real-value data
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=4)]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                            n_classes=3,
                                            model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")

# Fit model.
classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
               y=training_set.target,
               steps=2000)
```

Now that I have `classifier` trained, how might I save the model to disk so that later on I can write a script that does:

```
# classifier = <some reloading code that reinitializes the trained model>

accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(x=test_set.data,
                                     y=test_set.target)["accuracy"]
```

with minimal overhead and knowledge of the previous script?

Comment: You can still use `tf.train.Saver` to save the model. It doesn't matter how the graph was constructed.

Comment: Hi @Neal what are the parameters for Saver int his case? If you execute the above Python code and then do something like, saver = tf.train.Saver() you will get "no variables to save". There are a lot of examples with explicit tf.placeholder or tf.variable but I haven't come across any using data loaded from a .CSV like this. Any suggestions? Thank you